# Copy DB records in AWS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have 2 RDS databases on aws, qa and production. What I'm trying to do is copy all the records from our production db to qa. I created a new instance of production from a snapshot and pointed the connection string in my app from the qa instance to the new production instance. However the new production instance does not have the migrations needed by the app to run as we have not deployed those changes to yet.

So basically I have migrations in the qa db I'm looking to copy into the new instance of production so I can test the latest changes with current records.

Is there a way to add the migrations from the qa db into prod snapshot or is there a way to copy records from prod into qa which already has those migrations?

What I tried:

- small code change to see if redeploy would run migrations
- added empty migration and redeployed
  -- the prod db sees the new migration but none of the other ones

Comment: I apologize @JohnRotenstein for any confusion. I've reworded my question and hopefully cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

A Snapshot of an Amazon RDS database contains all data that was in the source database at the time the snapshot was made.

The Snapshot can be used to **create a new Amazon RDS database**, which will contain all the data from the Snapshot.

It is not possible to modify a Snapshot after it has been created.

As for "a way to copy records from prod into qa", this is not a native capability of Amazon RDS. You would need to use an SQL client to copy data between databases.